# how do i finish sorting this in descending order?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, collections, arraylist

We need to make two classes: GirlScoutCheck and CookieAnalyzerCheck. We need to get user input - ask them for the name of each girl until they type in runaway. Then we ask them for the number of cookie boxes each of the girl sold, and then add up the cookie boxes for each girl separately and multiply by 3.50. That's the total income. Then we sort them in descending order based on the total income. I have done almost everything. I just need help on sorting and printing the sorted info. Can anybody help me finish this? Thank you.

```
package Pcs;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CookieAnalyzerCheck {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    String name = "";
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

    do {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of each"
                + " girl Scout, or \"RUNAWAY\" "
                + "to exit.");
        name = kb.nextLine();
        if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("runaway")) {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of Thin Mints sold");
            int ThinMints = kb.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the number of Caramel Delights sold");
            int CaramelDelights = kb.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the number of Lemonades sold");
            int Lemonades = kb.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the number of ThanksALot sold");
            int ThanksALot = kb.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the number of MangoCremes sold");
            int MangoCremes = kb.nextInt();
            GirlScoutCheck ba = new GirlScoutCheck(name, ThinMints, CaramelDelights, Lemonades, ThanksALot, MangoCremes);
            al.add(ba);
            System.out.println(""); //makes output easier to read
            System.out.println();
        }
    } while (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("runaway"));


    GirlScoutCheck thisBA = (GirlScoutCheck) al.get(0);

    double maxBalance = thisBA.totalIncome;
    String maxName = thisBA.name;

    for (int i = 1; i < al.size(); i++) {
        thisBA = (GirlScoutCheck) al.get(i);
        if (thisBA.totalIncome > maxBalance) {
            //we have a new winner, so save the..
            maxBalance = thisBA.totalIncome;
            maxName = thisBA.name;

          int a= al.size();




            }
        }
    }


}



package Pcs;

import java.util.Collections;



public class GirlScoutCheck implements Comparable {
public String name;
public int ThinMints;
public int CaramelDelights;
public int Lemonades;
public int ThanksALot;
public int MangoCremes;
public int totalCookies;
public double totalIncome;

public GirlScoutCheck(String nm, int tm,int cd, int lem, int tal, int mc){
    name = nm;
    ThinMints = tm;
    CaramelDelights = cd;
    Lemonades = lem;
    ThanksALot = tal;
    MangoCremes = mc;
    totalCookies = ThinMints+CaramelDelights+Lemonades+ThanksALot+MangoCremes;
    totalIncome = totalCookies*3.50;
}

public int totalCookies(){
    return totalCookies;

}

public double totalIncome(){
    return totalIncome;

}
  public int compareTo(Object done){
   GirlScoutCheck b= (GirlScoutCheck)done;
   if (totalIncome>b.totalIncome){
       return 1;
   }
       else if(totalIncome<b.totalIncome)  {
           return -1;

       }
       else{
           return 0; 
   }


}


public String getName(){
        String nameParts[] = name.split(" ");
    String first = nameParts[0];
    String last = nameParts[1];

    return String.format(last + "," + first);
}








@Override
public String toString() {
    return "girlScoutCheck [name=" + getName() + ", ThinMints=" + ThinMints
            + ", CaramelDelights=" + CaramelDelights + ", Lemonades="
            + Lemonades + ", ThanksALot=" + ThanksALot + ", MangoCremes="
            + MangoCremes + ", totalCookies=" + totalCookies + "]"+ System.lineSeparator()+ " (total income for Thin Mints is $" +
                    ThinMints*3.50+ ") ( total income for Caramel Delights is $" +
                    CaramelDelights*3.50+ ") total income for Lemonades is $" +
                    Lemonades*3.50+ ")( total income for MangoCremes is $" +
                    MangoCremes*3.50+ ") (total income for ThanksALot is $" +
                    ThanksALot*3.50+ ")"+System.lineSeparator() ;

}


}
```

Comment: Could you please outline the problem, you are dealing with? Currently it is not very clear, what's the issue.

Comment: It seems you forget to share your code where you tried the sorting. Usually it is just calling the appropriate sort method (on Arrays or Collections), possibly with a custom Comparator (which might be necessary, as you would like to sort decreasing).

Comment: @Warlord- I can't figure out the way to sort at the end of CookieAnalyzerCheck class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're missing a few things in your `main` method:

- your variable `nf` is **never used**
- since you want to sort your `GirlScoutCheck`'s, I would recommend you to use a `TreeSet` to store them, instead of an `ArrayList`. A `TreeSet` is a collection of elements that are always sorted ([here is its javadoc entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)).

Ideally, you should declare and initialise that container as follows:

```
final Set<GirlScoutCheck> al = new TreeSet<>();
```

- You should always close streams and any external resource in general. *id est*: closing your `Scanner` before leaving your `main` method.

You could do that simply using the [Try-With-Resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax, as follows:

```
try (final Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    do {
        // your stuff
        kb.nextLine();
    } while (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("runaway"));
}
```

By the way, you might need to **consume the last line-feed** before reading the name of another girl: I would advise you to simply call `kb.nextLine();` right before re-entering your `do/while` loop (as I did in my example of the *Try-With-Resource* above).

Basically, your main method could simply be:

```
final Set<GirlScoutCheck> al = new TreeSet<>();

try (final Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    do {
        // your stuff
        kb.nextLine();
    } while (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("runaway"));
}

// from now on, al will contain all the GirlScoutCheck's ordered "as you want"

for (final GirlScoutCheck gsc : al) {
    System.out.println(gsc);
}
```

And... that's it!

---

Now, actually, to achieve this *"auto-ordering"*, we need to declare how to compare your `GirlScoutCheck`'s. You were doing the right thing making `GirlScoutCheck` implement `Comparable` :)

However, you should specify that you're implementing `Comparable<GirlScoutCheck>`. Thus, the signature of the `compareTo` method you're overriding becomes:

```
public int compareTo(final GirlScoutCheck other)
```

instead of:

```
public int compareTo(final Object other);
```

You can also simplify it like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(final GirlScoutCheck o) {
    return (int) (o.totalIncome - this.totalIncome);
}
```

One last point:
*Consistency with `equals` is required for ensuring sorted collections (such as `TreeSet`) are well-behaved.*
Source: [Implementing compareTo - JavaPractices](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10)

Thus, you should also implement `equals` and `hashcode` for your `GirlScoutCheck`'s, **using only the `totalIncome` field** (to be consistent with your `compareTo` implementation). Don't worry, your IDE could probably do it for you :)
And anyway, I can too. So here it is:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    long temp;
    temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(this.totalIncome);
    result = (prime * result) + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final GirlScoutCheck other = (GirlScoutCheck) obj;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.totalIncome) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.totalIncome)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**TL; DR**

Just...

- shove that piece code into your `GirlScoutCheck` class,
- replace its `compareTo` method by the one I gave you,
- be sure to make it implement `Comparable<GirlScoutCheck>` instead of just `Comparable`,
- modify the `main` method as I recommended...

and everything should work well ;)

Comment: Thanks! you were so helpful! i got my assignment done!:)